# Android App Statistics: What does 'Others' mean under 'Total Installs by User' metric?

Tags: android, google-developers-console

In 'Google Play Developer Console', Under 'Statistics' tab, I chose 'Total installs by user' from the dropdown.  In the bottom pane, i chose 'Device' to view 'TOTAL INSTALLS BY USER BY DEVICE'.

In the results, I see 'Others' as a category accounting for 33.33% installs.  The same is totally missing in 'INSTALLS ON ACTIVE DEVICES BY DEVICE'.

What does the 'Others' mean?  If those map to real users who later uninstalled the app, then it would be of great concern and I will spend effort in figuring out the root cause.

[image: Total Installs]

Comment: 33.3% of the installs are on devices that account for 5.56% or less of the installs total.  They cap the results in the top 10 otherwise they could list thousands of devices.

Comment: Based on the stats it means that the app was installed once on six other phones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the top of the page and click *Download* and export the statistics to CSV. Then you are gonna be able to see the different devices.

Some might have some strange name :)

[image]

Comment: I tried this now.  The numbers in the downloaded report doesn't seem to tally with the dashboard numbers.  In my case, the report had 102 rows but the dashboard shows only 41 (including 'Others').  Also, the device names listed in the dashboard (Ex: Samsung Galaxy J1 from my screenshot) are not showing up in the CSV report. :(

Answer (score 1):

Usually other would be generic unregistered devices which run on third party OS versions. Such are mobile phones running on CyanogenMod or Oxygen OS. If you go to the top and download the CSV file, then you will be able to gather some information about these devices.

Hope this will help.

Comment: In my case, it was more like @DeeV mentioned in the comments.  'Others' were also regular devices with shorthand names but the numbers don't really tally.  In 1 case, there is a device named 'arubaslim' with 1 'uninstall' count on 5th November but it never came up under 'install' count prior to that date.  so, as per the report, my app was uninstalled by someone on their device before even installing it!!

Comment: Or maybe whoever installed it changed the Device name and uninstalled your app.

Comment: I always thought the device names are provided by Google.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: You can actually customise them through the device settings.

Answer (score 1):

The number of total installs in this list is grouped by devices and sorted by the sum in descending order. As there are about 6000 different Android devices at the moment, this would be a very very long list. Thus, only the top 10 of that list are shown separately and all others are summed up under the label 'Others'.

For example there are probably also installs on Nexus 5 or Samsung Galaxy Note 7, but for each of them, there are less than the 5.56% of the Micromax Yunique, so they are not listed explicitly but added to the sum of others.